# Proof of Theorem 1, Calulus of Variation, Gelfand and Fomin

Tags: functional-equations, calculus-of-variations

[image]

This is theorem 1 on page 12 of Gelfand and Fomin. Why $\phi_1[h]-\phi_2[h]= \epsilon_2 ||h||$ instead of $\epsilon_1 ||h||-\epsilon_2||h||$? Is this a typo and he meant some $\epsilon_3=(\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is a typo. It should have been

$$\varphi_1[h]-\varphi_2[h]=\epsilon_2||h||-\epsilon_1||h||.$$

Comment: It is the typo in the translated version. The original (Russian) text says exactly what you have suggested.